# How do you count the values in a 2d list

Tags: python

I am trying to count how many numbers appear in each row in a 2d list and then return the values with a new variable . For example, I would to like to return the items that are greater than or equal to that length.

Here my list below

```
df = [[2,4,6,7],[3,4,],[2,4,6,8,12,24],[3,5,7,333,450],[4,20]]
```

I would like to create a new variable and return each row that is longer than 3.

```
df2 =[[2,4,6,7],[2,4,6,8,12,24],[3,5,7,333,450]]
```

I would like to create a new variable and return each row with exactly 2 elements.

```
df3 = [[3,4,],[4,20]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehensions to do this. In this case, you can check the `len` of each sublist, and use that to filter out which sublists you want to keep/discard.

```
>>> df = [[2,4,6,7],[3,4,],[2,4,6,8,12,24],[3,5,7,333,450],[4,20]]
>>> [i for i in df if len(i) > 3]
[[2, 4, 6, 7], [2, 4, 6, 8, 12, 24], [3, 5, 7, 333, 450]]
>>> [i for i in df if len(i) == 2]
[[3, 4], [4, 20]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most efficient solution but a succinct way to do this:

```
df = [[2,4,6,7],[3,4,],[2,4,6,8,12,24],[3,5,7,333,450],[4,20]]

df3 = filter(lambda l: len(l) > 3, df)
df2 = filter(lambda l: len(l) == 2, df)

print(list(df2))
print(list(df3))
```

output:

```
[[3, 4], [4, 20]]
[[2, 4, 6, 7], [2, 4, 6, 8, 12, 24], [3, 5, 7, 333, 450]]
```